# How do I read multiple tokens between characters in java?

Tags: java, delimiter

I am doing a project where I need to read multiple lines that contains user data from a txt file. This data will create a profile.

For example:

```
name,lastname,email,hobbies1;hobbies2...hobbiesN,activity1;activity2...activityN

name2,lastname2,email.... and so on
```

I don't know how many hobbies or activities are there so I have to set them into an array. All of variables are on one line. 
I tried using delimiter and split, but when I move onto the next line I get inputMismatchException.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to change the format.

Instead of separating every field with `,` try using `;` for separating different types of attributes and `,` for elements of arrays. The end result will be something like:

`name; lastname; email; hobbies1, hobbies2, ..., hobbiesN; activity1, activity2, ..., activityN`

First you split the `String` using `;` as delimiter, then for those fields that allows for arrays you divide the array in its elements by splitting that sub`String` with `,` as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Read lines, then split on comma, and split on semi-colon where needed.

Don't use `Scanner` for line-reading a file.

```
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        String   name =       (fields.length >= 1 ? fields[0] : "");
        String   lastname =   (fields.length >= 2 ? fields[1] : "");
        String   email =      (fields.length >= 3 ? fields[2] : "");
        String[] hobbies =    (fields.length >= 4 ? fields[3].split(";") : new String[0]);
        String[] activities = (fields.length >= 5 ? fields[4].split(";") : new String[0]);
        System.out.println("name=" + name +
                         ", lastname=" + lastname +
                         ", email=" + email +
                         ", hobbies=" + Arrays.toString(hobbies) +
                         ", activities=" + Arrays.toString(activities));
    }
}
```

*test.txt*

```
name,lastname,email,hobbies1;hobbies2...hobbiesN,activity1;activity2...activityN
name2,lastname2,email
```

*Output*

```
name=name, lastname=lastname, email=email, hobbies=[hobbies1, hobbies2...hobbiesN], activities=[activity1, activity2...activityN]
name=name2, lastname=lastname2, email=email, hobbies=[], activities=[]
```